# displaying unique strings from an array

Tags: iphone

i want to get unique strings from an array and to store those strings into another array..... give logic or sample code for this ...............thanks in advance

Comment: you are looking for NSSet i beleive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *uniqueArray = [[NSSet setWithArray: yourArray] allObjects];
```